# focus doesn't start on body Angular accessibility

Tags: angular, focus, accessibility

On my site, if you click on a link in the footer, on the next page, if you press the tab key, focus starts on a link in the footer, not at the top of a new page like a visually-impaired user would expect.  This is an Angular application.  Does anyone know why this is?  Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: how are you loading the pages, via AJAX and just replacing the `<main>` or similar? Or do you actually render a whole new page when the URL changes?

Comment: We're using routing and router-outlet on the pages and Universal/SSR

Answer (score 0):

For links in the footer, because it's an Angular application, because it's a SPA, the page never reloads like normal for the browser to set focus on the page body.  The body of the page in the router-outlet changes, but the footer never changes.  In footer.component.ts, subscribing to router.events and utilizing the NavigationEnd event is a solution:

```
this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const mainHeader = document.getElementById('main-app-content');
    if (mainHeader) {
      console.log(mainHeader);
      mainHeader.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

And in app.component.html (Angular components become divs and can't get focus)

```
<router-outlet id="main-app-content" tabindex="0"></router-outlet>
```